# Drush command to download AND enable a module

Tags: drush

To download and install a module, I run:

```
drush dl module_name
drush en module_name -y
```

I put that in a Bash script function, and just call "drin module_name" to simplify.

```
function drin(){
  drush dl $1
  drush en $1 -y
}
```

Is there a one-line command in Drush to download and enable a module?

Comment: There is a proposal for several improvements in download and enable. See this issue http://drupal.org/node/1364814

Comment: There is an update in the latest drush that does this. See new selected answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The following will download and enable the module:

```
drush en module_name -y
```

Edit:  The download (dl) command is not needed.  When trying to enable a module that is not downloaded yet, Drush will ask if you want to download it and then ask if you want to enable it. The -y automates the "yes" answers to these questions.

This was added in [Drush 6.0.0](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/tag/6.0.0) `(#1364814 by eiriksm, jonhattan: Added Extend pm-enable to offer downloading the project for missing extensions.)`

Comment: Can you expand on how this is different than the other answers?

Comment: It is only one command. The others listed have two commands.  When you try to enable a module that isn't already downloaded, Drush ask you if you want to download it and then ask you if you want to enable it.  The -y at the end automatically answers those checks as 'yes'.

Comment: I think this is a new implementation. At the time I posted this QA, this was not possible.

Comment: This didn't work for me, using a fresh install of drush from the repository.

Comment: This didn't work.  I tried the following: 
`drush en schema -y` and got this:
schema was not found and will not be enabled.                        [warning]
There were no extensions that could be enabled.                      [ok]

Comment: Okay, this approach works fine on Drush 6.3.0.

Comment: This will also download and enable any module dependencies for the module(s) you're currently trying to download. Check the answer of Krishna Kanth to see how you can download and enable multiple modules in a single command.

Answer (score 18):

```
drush dl module_name && drush en module_name -y
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this is the same as typing in the commands twice, or using a semi-colon to separate them. I was looking for an actual drush subcommand.

Comment: Yes though your original question, before you edited it, was asking for a "single line solution" which it is.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm sorry about the confusion. That's why I edited it to clarify and not mislead the next contributors.

Answer (score 7):

Downloading and enabling a module can be done with `drush en project_name`. It asks for a confirmation; if you don't want to confirm, use the `-y` parameter.

```
drush en project_name -y
```

You can download more projects with the same command.

```
drush en rules views token -y
```

For a list of some basic Drush commands see [Basics drush commands](http://krishnakanth.info/drupal-drush-commands/drupal-shell-basic-drush-commands-drupal-developers).

Comment: Yes, 'drush en' works with more recent versions of drush

Answer (score 1):

In Drush 9, you download a module with `composer require drupal/module_name`.

See the new documentation for Drush 9 on [`drush pm:download`](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/pm/pm:download/).

After, you will need to enable the module with `drush pm:enable module_name`.

*Other useful commands for modules are:

- See all the modules installed

  ```
  drush pm:list
  ```
- Uninstall a module

  ```
  drush pm:uninstall module_name
  ```

Answer (score 0):

in Drupal 8 you no longer use Drush. Use `composer require drupal/module_name` instead.

Comment: This downloads it but does not enable it. How do I enable it in command line for D8?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I am not sure why it was necessary to edit my comment since there was no substantive change in what you edited. In fact, by changing it you took the command out of its own element which allows users to double click on it to copy and paste it, which was the whole point in why I placed it in a code element in the first place. I understand you're a moderator, but I fail to understand your reasons here.